# APNS - what is the cost for sending out a message?

Tags: apple-push-notifications

Do the carriers (say AT&T) charge a fee for sending messages through APNS? If so, where can I find the pricing details?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware there are no costs to the sender... The only possible costs would be on the customer's side.. if they do not have an all inclusive data plan or if they have gone over their data limits. But the notifications are absolutely tiny in size data wise.. so that really shouldn't be an issue.

So basically it's sent as data and not through the cellular networks.

Comment: You need a server and must be in the apple developer program which costs you 100$ per year. There are no per message costs.